# What is a property object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

I am not new to python, but I have a pretty basic question here.

I was playing around with python and found that there is the type property

```
>>> property
<type 'property'>
```

But I have only heard of properties in the function context.

```
>>> a = property()
<property object at 0x0246C090>
```

But what about property objects? What are they use? Property methods are not very intuitive or suggestive

```
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__delete__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__set__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'deleter', 'fdel', 'fget', 'fset', 'getter', 'setter']
```

Thank you for the attention!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `property` object is what you are actually thinking of as a property. Consider this example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = 0

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar + 5
```

`Foo.bar` is a property object which has a `__get__` method. When you write something like

```
x = Foo()
print(x.bar)
```

the lookup for `x.bar` finds that `type(x).bar` has a `__get__` method, and so the attribute lookup becomes equivalent to

```
type(x).bar.__get__(x, type(x))
```

which produces the value `x._bar + 5`.

The use of `property` as a decorator somewhat obscures the fact that `bar` is a `property` object. An equivalent defintion is

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self._bar = 0

     bar = property(lambda self: self._bar + 5)
```

which shows more explicitly that you are creating a `property` object with the given `lambda` expression as the getter for that property, and binding the object to the class attribute `bar`.

The `property` class (along with instance methods, class methods, and static methods) is a specific application of Python's general descriptor protocol, which defines the behavior of class attributes with `__get__`, `__set__`, and/or `__del__` methods.

Answer (score 6):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,*costs):
        self.costs = costs
    def item_cost(self):
        return sum(self.costs)
```

now you can do

```
MyClass(1,2,3,4).item_cost() #prints 10
```

but we can make it a property

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,*costs):
        self.costs = costs
    @property
    def item_cost(self):
        return sum(self.costs)
```

and now we can access it as a simple variable

```
MyClass(1,2,3,4).item_cost
```

you could also create a setter for the value with

```
  ...
   @item_cost.setter
   def set_item_cost(self,value):
         pass #do something with value
  ...
 MyClass(1,2,3,4).item_cost = "yellow"
```

In general I find them to be sort of an anti-pattern... but some folks like em

(side note you could also make it a property using it as a regular function instead of a decorator  `MyClass.item_cost_prop = property(MyClass.item_cost)` )

Answer (score 4):

A property is an attribute object containing a getter and a setter method.

Comment: Basically, with that notation you are avoiding the decorator notation.

Comment: This doesn't explain what properties actually do.