# Calling property setter using event handler

Tags: python, event-handling

I use following class to define event:

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.handlers = set()

    def handle(self, handler):
        self.handlers.add(handler)
        return self

    def unhandle(self, handler):
        try:
            self.handlers.remove(handler)
        except:
            raise ValueError("Handler is not handling this event, so cannot unhandle it.")
        return self

    def fire(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for handler in self.handlers:
            print(handler)
            handler(*args, **kwargs)

    def getHandlerCount(self):
        return len(self.handlers)

    __iadd__ = handle
    __isub__ = unhandle
    __call__ = fire
    __len__  = getHandlerCount
```

I have some model class defined like this:

```
class SomeModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 0
        self.fooChanged = Event()

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value
        self.fooChanged(value)
```

Now, suppose that I want to change `foo` like this:

```
model = SomeModel()
other_model = SomeModel()

model.fooChanged += other_model.foo

model.foo = 1
```

After `model.foo = 1`, I get following error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Now, suppose that I use this code for defining model:

```
class SomeModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 0
        self.fooChanged = Event()

    def get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    def set_foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value
        self.fooChanged(value)

    foo = property(get_foo, set_foo)
```

and this code to change the value of `foo`:

```
model = SomeModel()
other_model = SomeModel()

model.fooChanged += other_model.set_foo

model.foo = 1
```

Second version works fine, however, it seems little un-Pythonic to me. I have to define `get_foo` method, which I'd like to avoid (since properties are available). Is there some other workaround here, so first version of code could run?

*Note*: error will depend on `self._foo` type. If it's `None`, it will return error stating that `NoneType` is not callable, if it's string, error will state that `str` object is not callable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037692/what-is-a-property-object) to be very informative and it pushed me in the right direction.

Using this knowledge, I was able to solve this problem by using:

```
model.fooChanged += lambda value: type(other_model).foo.__set__(other_model, value)
```

or

```
model.fooChanged += lambda value: type(other_model).foo.fset(other_model, value)
```

The later line looks more Pythonic to me, since no calls for double-underscore functions are made.

Comment: err didnt see this while start writes my answer, glad you find a solution.

Comment: You have wrote it slightly different, but that's working too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

while you write `model.fooChanged += other_model.foo`, I guess what you actually want is its setter method, but as `other_model.foo` is a [property object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work), you have to get from its class `other_model.__class__.foo.fset`, write as:

```
model.fooChanged += lambda value: other_model.__class__.foo.fset(other_model, value)
```

OTOH, I think your second version is pythonic to me, as:

> Explicit is better than implicit.